# How to cleanup database in kubernetes after service is deleted?

Tags: kubernetes

Consider the following things are already satisfied. 
1. The maria-db is running in separate pod and is pre-installed. 
2. When we deploy a new service it is able to connect to maria-db and create SCHEMA in it.

But the final requirement is when the service is deleted then it should cleanup the SCHEMA.
I have tried writing a job with post-delete tag.

Comment: trying to understand why on deleting service you need schema delete up, shouldn't be it on pod deletion?

Comment: No we have created a schema as part of the our service installation and will be only used by our service so after the service is deleted, the database entries and everything must be cleared off.

Comment: How are you going to create *services*? Are you planning to manage their releases via Helm?

Comment: I don't think Gokul is referring to Kubernetes objects with `kind: Service`, I think he just means some web service or microservice or application that talks to the database.

Comment: Yes @AmitKumarGupta I did meant it as some microservice .

Answer (score 1):

So just a thought, you could possible do this by using a [Admission Control](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/extensible-admission-controllers/) i.e your logic could possible be along the lines of:

`Delete Pod Requested --> Hits Addmission Control --> Addmission Controller Removes Schema --> Pod Deleted`

However this would be a lot of custom code and you would need a way to identify the Schema that that particular service has created in the DB.

Comment: But i want i to run independently without our any interaction like JOB in kubernetes. And if there is replica then new pod comes-up with scheme and data which at current state. Even we cannot delete the pod as it would used by other micro-service.

Comment: Well then depending on the programming language you would have to do something in a graceful shutdown period, this would need to be done in every service separately, I am not sure of your current setup but the above would be the route I would explore as it would allow me to handle more case scenarios as I could code in those scenarios, and wouldn't be dependant on any single microservice. It is also more Kubernetes Native, not relying on Helm

Comment: The programming language used is Python but i think the job written can be independent of the programming language used as the it would run independently after the termination of the micro-service and it has to only modify the schema inside the maria-db pod given all credentials.